# Preventing tampering of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, access-control, authorization, system-compromise

If a server is compromised, an attacker could add his own public key to authorized_keys. How is this prevented? Who should have what access to the file?

Comment: If the server is compromised an attacker can just start their own SSH server with their key hardcoded in it and not even care about your own authorized_keys.

Comment: If a server is compromised, you cannot rely on it unless you rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: "If a server is compromised" Rule #1 of the 10 Immutable Laws of Security: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not solely your computer anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a server is compromised, an attacker could add his own public key to authorized_keys. How is this prevented?

Modification of a user's `authorized_keys` file by an attacker is prevented **by** keeping the system from being compromised to the point of the attacker being able to modify arbitrary critical files in the first place, and to a lesser extent by ensuring that this critical file has permissions that do not allow arbitrary users to change its contents.

> Who should have what access to the file?

Only the user owning the file should have write access (including to its parent directories), but read access is in principle safe as the file only contains public key data. (The corresponding private key is stored on the system which the user is connecting from.) In practice, there is no reason to set anything more permissive than 0600, and the SSH server *should* reject the file if it has permissions that allow it to be modified or replaced by someone other than the owner.

**Consider the scenario you are describing.** The attacker, in that case, already has root access, or effectively so, as they are able to modify a user's `authorized_keys` file. At that point, there is no reason to do something as mundane as installing an additional SSH key that allows logging in as that user; as has been pointed out already, it's far better to install a custom SSH server (which has all logging ripped out, for one, and probably tries to mask or conceal itself against the administrator, for two).

**The only scenario in which it seems to me** to be meaningful to even consider modifying a user's `authorized_keys` file is if the attacker only managed to gain access to that user's account, and want to do what they can to maintain access at least to that account. But if the user looks at that file, unless the user has something like *dozens* of legitimately authorized keys, the extra line is likely to stand out like a sore thumb.

And even in such a scenario, in the vast majority of cases there are likely far better ways of ensuring continued access to the compromised system.

If the attacker is able to gain root-equivalent access, there are many, many ways to ensure continued access that are far, far harder to detect, let alone clean up, even by a vigilant user or system administrator.

Comment: Is it true then, that whenever my colleague leaves his machine to get a drink or something, and forgets to lock it, I can quickly append my public key to his authorized_keys and thereafter pretend to be him whenever I like? If so, that's a weakness that an old fashioned password-only login mechanism doesn't have (or at least it wouldn't be as trivially easy to do).

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge [Does SSH authorized_keys violate the principle of “re-authenticate before password change”?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/59501/2138) In short: Yes, but we tend to accept that risk. At the level you are asking about, it's also a trivially mitigatable risk. If you are really paranoid, set up something like Tripwire to monitor each user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and notify an appropriate user on changes.

Answer (score 4):

If a server is compromised, it is basically game over. You can restore from known good backups or reinstall, and you can do some post-mortem analyses to find out how they gained entry, but that sistem is hosed and **should not be repaired** but reinstalled.

So, nothing prevents attacker who've gained superuser privileges to modify `authorized_keys`. Normally, only the user to whom this file belongs (and root, of course) should be able to access it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/852434/how-to-protect-authorized-keys-file) existing answer.

Consider the use case of the server in your scenario, particularly how often and diverse SSH sessions will be, and exercise the principle of least privilege accordingly.

Most of the compromise scenarios that come to mind stem from improper hardening (i.e regarding user accounts) and/or other configuration flaws.

Answer (score 0):

changes can happen and bite you, always.

auditing with records saved on another computer is mandatory.

see for example OSSEC